# Run/debug configuration errors

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've recently imported a project and I can't seem to compile or run it. I am required to add a configuration file and at times it asks me to update to gradle format.
I've been told that my gradle files may be old but that hasn't really helped me solve my proble. I have as well reviewed some answers on here but none seems to work not even the invalidating cache and restarting android studio. What is causing this and  can I do about it?

[No run or debug functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWUd6.png)

[Add a configuration screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcLSz.png)

Comment: it says something is wrong with your manifest

Comment: Yes that it is not found or doesn't exist but my manifest is there. I'm not sure of how to make it visible to the IDE

Comment: Please paste the full text of your manifest file. It says "doesn't exist" **OR** "has incorrect root tag", so something is wrong with the XML in the file.